# Why this code is not working for dynamic carousel in laravel 5?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, carousel

I am trying to make a dynamic carousel in laravel 5 ecommerce web based application.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop)

But I want that product(s) should be retrieved from the database, which I successfully retrieved.

Here's the code of the controller method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $carousels = Carousel::where('display', 'Enabled')->get();
        $products = DB::table('carousel_product AS cp')
                    ->join('products AS p', 'p.id', '=', 'cp.product_id')
                    ->join('carousels AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'cp.carousel_id')
                    ->select(
                        'p.id AS prod_id',
                        'p.name AS prod_name',
                        'p.code AS prod_code',
                        'p.short_description AS p_short_desc',
                        'p.price AS prod_price',
                        'p.discount_price AS prod_disc_price'
                    )->get();
        return view( 'home', compact( 'carousels', 'products' ) );
    }
```

Here's the bootstrap carousel dynamic:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="carousels">
       @foreach( $carousels as $carousel )
           <div class="carousels-header">
               <h2><span class="line-center">{{ $carousel->name }}</span></h2>
           </div>

           <div class="carousel slide" id="{{ Safeurl::make($carousel->name) }}">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="carousel-inner">
                       <?php $i = 0; ?>
                       @foreach( $products as $product )
                           <div class="item @if($i === 0) {{ 'active' }} @endif">
                               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                   <img src="{{ url('/images/uploads/products', Safeurl::make($product->prod_code) . '.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive">
                               </div>
                               <?php $i++; ?>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#{{ Safeurl::make($carousel->name) }}" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#{{ Safeurl::make($carousel->name) }}" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get after trying the above code is 3 products in each `.item` class while actually, it only needs to be 1 product in each `.item` class, and by default, the first product has to be `.active`.

**EDIT 1:**

The image is sliding properly, but when the user lands for the first time on the page, he can see only 3 product images while actually, there should be 4 product images.

When he clicks on either of the arrows, all the three images move to the respective side and again there are 3 product images seen instead of 4.

What I want:

When the user lands on the page, he should see all 4 product images. And when clicked on the arrows, only 1 product image should be moved. Just like the tutorial.

**EDIT 2:** The problem I guess is in `jquery`:

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)).addClass('rightest');
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

How do I amend the above jQuery code ?

Kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you create a .item class for each products with single image alone. But you set a class "**col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3**" which makes your images size into (fullwidth/4) . So change the class like "**col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12**"

Comment: **col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3** is what I want.. Each `.item` class should have 1 product which will be 4 products when the user lands. And when he clicks on the either of the arrows, only 1 product should be moved..

Comment: Yes.. I need to show more than 1 carousels if they are `Enabled`.

Comment: 1.You getting carousels which are enabled and all product carousel images but you are not relate these images with corresponding carousel so do it first. 2. If your product have only 4 images means try to put these images inside the .item class. This will move the product while clicking a arrow keys

Comment: Well, for the point number 1, I have already build the relationship of `Many-To-Many`. For the point 2, there can be any number of product, no restriction at all, and once it reaches the last product of the carousel, it will start over it again.

Comment: You want to show single product image in a view(which means only showing 1 image at a time).

Comment: At a time there will be 4 images when the user first lands on the page. When he clicks on either of the arrows, only 1 image should be moved.

Comment: Your code almost do that job only, but your syntax was mismatch with your reference. Try to fix those changes by compare with demo

Comment: There is no syntax error in that code. There is logical error which I am unable to find it. The logical error is somewhere inside the `@foreach($products as $product)` loop, I am failing to debug that.

Comment: Did you get rendered images(html view)...?. Remove the **<div class="row">** element. and you should call **$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 40000
});** call this javascript with your id of carousel name

Comment: **$('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 40000 });** is not needed for my application.

Answer (score 0):

All this

```
<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and etc ..

change this

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/mystyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```